# Difficult changing groups in Crystal Reports 12 due to windows size. Resizable?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

This is in `Crystal Reports 2008 version 12.2.0.290`

I am working on a report a previous employee created. I want to change one of the groups but the window size is too small to see the full field name and I don't see any way to resize it or to see the entire field name. Many of the groups are different only by the right most portion of the field name for example Here are groups 1-4:

```
SUMMARY_AGED_ACCOUNTS_RECIEVABLE_1
SUMMARY_AGED_ACCOUNTS_RECIEVABLE_2
SUMMARY_AGED_ACCOUNTS_RECIEVABLE_3
SUMMARY_AGED_ACCOUNTS_RECIEVABLE_4
```

Since I can't see all the way to the right it is an annoying process of trial and error.

Secondly in design and previous views the section chooser area to the left is too small and truncates the field name in a similar manner. Is there anyway to resize these portions of the program? Is there another area of the program where I can choose groups and see the entire field? You can see what I mean in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: To the extent I know you we can't increase the size of the `section display` or the `change group window`. 

One option you can try for groups is instead of creating the groups with field names you can create the groups with names `Group1`, `Group 2` etc... and use that formula to group so that you can clearly see what formula you are using in grouping.

For the filed names see in the `field explorer`

Comment: I have seen Crystal Reports .rpt files modified in Visual Studio. I wonder if that would be help get around this issue.

Comment: May be....I am not sure though no knowledge on visual studio